# DllImport parameters char *TagIDs[]

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Hi Im trying to import c++ library in c# code
his definition:

```
void IRFR_GetUIDs(char *reply, char *TagIDs[], CString *TagNum);
```

how my function  Should look like

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This function cannot be imported with p/invoke. It has a `CString` parameter which is a native C++ class and thus inaccessible to p/invoke. Either wrap the DLL with a other DLL exposing a p/invoke friendly interface, or wrap the DLL with a C++/CLI assembly.

Comment: ok but what with second parameter
char *TagIDs[] 
How this should be translated to c# ?

Comment: That depends on what the semantics are